# Best Solution for PHP Index.php Contoller

Tags: php

What's the best way of including PHP files to link all php files together to allow for arrays to pass through each file.

Currently I'm am using a switch to include a html and php file when a case value is passed through from a .htaccess file.

**.HTACCESS**

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=homepage
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?page=login
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    switch($_GET['page']) {
        case 'login':
            include('login.php');
            include('login.html');
        break;

        default:
            include('index.html');
        break;
    }
}
```

This technique doesn't seem like the best solution, as you will eventually end up with a huge switch statement containing all pages for the site.

Is there a better solution?

Also, I am having issues passing an array through to a folder called 'account' the array will contain details of who is logged in etc, but as soon as I add code to the folder, the array from the main site doesn't get included.

How do I access an array from outisde the folder inside the 'account' folder?

Comment: Look at what ever MVC framework and use there routing and MVC structure in stead of this 1900's logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a large switch you can do this:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) === true)
   if(file_exists($_GET['page'] . '.html') === true) {
       include($_GET['page'] . '.php');
       include($_GET['page'] . '.html');
    } else {
       header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
       echo 'Page not found';
       exit;
    }
} else {
   include('index.html');
}
```

This limits you that the `.html` and the `.php` file have to be named same as the according `page` GET parameter.

Comment: I would recommend not to solve it like that. What about `index.php?page=phpinfo`!?

Comment: It will display a `404 Not Found` message/header to the client.

Comment: What would happen with regards to passing an array from these pages to scripts in a folder called 'account'?

Comment: Really don't know what you're talking about in that point @Richy